# json_encode - JSON inválido

Tags: php, json, web-service

Criei um código PHP para buscar informações de um banco de dados (MySQL) e "transformar" em JSON. Eu usei o `json_encode` para tal.

O JSON de saída parecia estar correto, mas quando uso algum validador de JSON, sempre retorna um erro `Unexpected token`.

O que mais me intriga, é que se eu digitar manualmente o JSON de saída no validador, o mesmo funciona! Se eu der um Ctrl + C e Ctrl + V, ocorre o erro.

Para verificar o resultado JSON: http://devsa.url.ph/?cod=all

O que pode ser?

```
<?php
include('connectdb.php');

$something = $_GET['cod'];
$sqlcode = mysql_query("Select descricao from Produtos Where codigo='$something'");
$sqlcode2 = mysql_query("Select descricao from Produtos");

$jsonObj = array();

if ($something == 'all') {
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($sqlcode2)) {
        $jsonObj[] = $result;
    }
} else {
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($sqlcode)) {
        $jsonObj[] = $result;
    }
}

$final_res = json_encode($jsonObj);

echo $final_res;
?>
```

Comment: Note que existe algum caractere antes de abrir o colchete. Use as setas direcionais que você irá perceber.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um provável diagnóstico pode ser o tipo de codificação.

Para corrigir isso, informe o cabeçalho do tipo de arquivo, não deixe nenhum tipo de carácter antes e depois da saída, garanta que sua tag `<?php` é a primeira coisa do arquivo e remova a tag `?>` do final do arquivo, ou então adicione um `exit;`:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$final_res = json_encode($jsonObj);
echo $final_res;
exit;
```

Verifique qual o *encoding* do seu banco de dados, do arquivo PHP que está imprimindo os dados e o do arquivo que está recebendo os dados. Se possível coloque todos em `UTF-8` sem [BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223926/3497987) <sup>inglês</sup>.

**Complemento**:

[image: Resposta vista do wireshark]

Observe que há dois arquivos com BOM no início.

o código para cabeçalho do php:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8;");
```

Comment: Ótima resposta! O problema era exatamente esse "tal de BOM", o que eu fiz, foi abrir o arquivo php no notepad++, fui ate o menu "Formatar" > "Codificação em UTF-8 (Sem BOM)".