# Long Polling com mysqli não retorna dados

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli

Os dados do **data.php** do banco de dados do arquivo não retorna, se eu altero todo o **data.php** pra qualquer texto html ele retorna funcionando o long polling, mas se eu tento usar mysqli não retorna nada.

Oque posso fazer para corrigir esse problema ?

Não é erro de SELECT poque se você abrir o **data.php** separado ele retorna os dados.

**index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Conteúdo</h3>
        <div id="response"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**server.php**

```
<?php
// arquivo cujo conteúdo será enviado ao cliente
$dataFileName = 'data.php';
while ( true )
{
    $requestedTimestamp = isset ( $_GET [ 'timestamp' ] ) ? (int)$_GET [ 'timestamp' ] : null;

    // o PHP faz cache de operações "stat" do filesystem. Por isso, devemos limpar esse cache
    clearstatcache();
    $modifiedAt = filemtime( $dataFileName );

    if ( $requestedTimestamp == null || $modifiedAt > $requestedTimestamp )
    {
        $data = file_get_contents( $dataFileName );

        $arrData = array(
            'content' => $data,
            'timestamp' => $modifiedAt
        );

        $json = json_encode( $arrData );

        echo $json;

        break;
    }
    else
    {
        sleep( 2 );
        continue;
    }
}
?>
```

**client.js**

```
function getContent( timestamp )
{
    var queryString = { 'timestamp' : timestamp };

    $.get ( 'server.php' , queryString , function ( data )
    {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
        $( '#response' ).html( obj.content );

        // reconecta ao receber uma resposta do servidor
        getContent( obj.timestamp );
    });
}

$( document ).ready ( function ()
{
    getContent();
});
```

**data.php**

```
<?php
$conexao = mysqli_connect ("localhost","usuario","senha","db");
$resulta = mysqli_query ($conexao,"SELECT * FROM nome");
while ($exibe = mysqli_fetch_array($resulta)){
?>

<?php echo $exibe['nomes']; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro de javascript no console do navegador? no data.php evite usar a tag de fechamento do php. [relacionado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36835/json-encode-json-inv%C3%A1lido/36842#36842)

Comment: @rray O Código esta tudo ok funcionando perfeitamente, parece que o long polling não atualiza códigos php só textos, se você testar usando algum texto no data.php vera que funciona muito bem o long polling, mas se usar uma função mysql ou php já não pega.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O  problema está no `file_get_contents()` do seu código.

Quando você usa o `file_get_contents()` em um arquivo php (do jeito que foi usado no seu código), ele vai retornar a **string do código**; ou seja, ele não vai ser processado como php.

O que faria o código ser interpretado como esperado seria o função `include`, mas não sei se  nesse caso se aplicaria.

Vejo que você está tentando verificar a **data de modificação** do arquivo, mas isso seria ineficiente, visto que você teria que verificar uma data no banco (já que a consulta é no banco); e, em nenhum momento, há no seu script alteração da data do arquivo (por meio de alguma modificação).

Já utilizei um script bem parecido com esse para estudar **Long Polling**, e o seu script está bem parecido com que eu usei. Posso lhe assegurar que ele não vai funcionar para operações com o **MYSQL**.

A única forma de fazer funcionar (não é uma das melhores), é trocar

isso:

```
$dataFileName = 'data.php'
```

por isso:

```
$dataFileName = 'http://localhost/sua_pasta_de_testes/data.php';
```

Assim, você estaria realmente pegando uma resposta HTML do seu script PHP já executado, e não ele apenas como um arquivo em uma pasta. Pois o file_get_contents funciona tanto para arquivos do seu diretório como para urls (se a diretiva `allow_url_fopen` do seu PHP.ini estiver configurada como `On`).

Comment: Entendi, obrigado estou estudando long polling e ta difícil... se você afirma que esse sistema não vai funcionar pra mysql acho que vou partir pra outro. mesmo alterando não vem resultado, mas isso não iria me servir.

Comment: Se você encontrou algo melhor no seus estudos e poder me passar agradeço.

Comment: Acho que a resposta do @Beraldo vai poder te ajudar bastante. Não testei, mas a lógica parece estar correta.

Answer (score 2):

Esse exemplo fui eu que postei em meu blog. Há tempos muitos me perguntam como adaptar o exemplo para usar banco de dados. Veja como fazer usando PDO e SQLite:

```
$dbFile = 'comments.db';

$PDO = new PDO( "sqlite:" . $dbFile );

while ( true )
{
    $requestedTimestamp = isset ( $_GET [ 'timestamp' ] ) ? (int)$_GET [ 'timestamp' ] : time();

    $stmt = $PDO->prepare( "SELECT author, comment, timestamp FROM comments WHERE timestamp >= :requestedTimestamp" );

    $stmt->bindParam( ':requestedTimestamp', $requestedTimestamp );
    $stmt->execute();

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

    if ( count( $rows ) > 0 )
    {
        $json = json_encode( $rows );

        echo $json;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        sleep( 2 );
        continue;
    }
}
```

Se preferir usar MySQLi em vez de PDO, basta alterar um pouco o script, modificando a classe PDO pela MysQLi. Mas a lógica é a mesma.

Atualizei o post original com o exemplo usando PDO e SQLite. Veja-o aqui: http://rberaldo.com.br/server-push-long-polling-php-ios/

Comment: 1+. Mas, se você já está usando o `fetchAll`, por que então dar um `foreach` para realocar os mesmos dados para um outro `array`? basta apenas dar um `json_encode($rows)`

Comment: @wallace-maxters de fato, nem precisa do foreach. Foi força do hábito. Vou editar.