# Por que omitir a tag de fechamento do PHP?

Tags: php

Todo bom livro de boas práticas e wiki começa com esta "regra" mas ninguém oferece boas razões.

Quais as boas razões para ignorar a tag de fechamento `?>` do PHP?

Comment: Um [exemplo de problema](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36835/91) com a tag de fechamento

Comment: +1 boa pergunta :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uma boa razão é para evitar que espaços em branco indesejados apareçam em nossos arquivos, que possivelmente pode causar o [Erro - Cannot modify header information](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-do-php-cannot-modify-header-information). Como pode ver nessa pergunta, existem diversas causas para esse tipo de erro que pode passar despercebidos pelas IDEs.

Omitir a tag de fechamento em arquivos puramente PHP é também uma [recomendação da PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), um conjunto de regras de estilo de código seguida por Frameworks PHP amplamente utilizados, como Zend Framework, Symfony, Laravel, entre outros. Seguir um estilo de código em nosso projeto resulta em um código uniforme dentro da equipe e ter uma referencia que é utilizado em vários lugares é melhor ainda.

Por fim, segue um trecho da [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php):

> A tag de fechamento de um bloco PHP ao final de um arquivo é opcional,
>   e em alguns casos omiti-la é útil ao usar include ou require, assim
>   espaço em branco indesejado não irá aparecer ao final dos arquivos, e
>   você ainda será capaz de adicionar cabeçalhos a resposta após. Também
>   é útil se você usar output buffering, e você não quer ter adicionado
>   um espaço em branco ao final das partes geradas por arquivos
>   incluídos.

Answer (score 3):

Como citado no próprio manual do PHP http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

> A tag de fechamento de um bloco PHP ao final de um arquivo é opcional,
>   e em alguns casos omiti-la é útil ao usar include ou require, assim
>   espaço em branco indesejado não irá aparecer ao final dos arquivos, e
>   você ainda será capaz de adicionar cabeçalhos a resposta após. Também
>   é útil se você usar output buffering, e você não quer ter adicionado
>   um espaço em branco ao final das partes geradas por arquivos
>   incluídos.