# Codigo PHP nao é reconhecido na pagina

Tags: php, ajax, aplicação-web

Fiz um menu com Ajax e ele troca dinamicamente o conteúdo, até aí tudo bem, mas o problema é que quando insiro um código PHP na página ele não reconhece o código e exibe as escritas, aparece isso ao invés de executar o código. Alguém sabe o que esta acontecendo??

Obs: antes do Ajax funcionava normalmente.

```
prepare("SELECT * FROM empresa"); 
$executa = $empresa->execute(); 
if($executa){
  while($reg = $empresa->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){ 
  /* Para recuperar um ARRAY utilize PDO::FETCH_ASSOC */ 
?> 
txt_empresa
?> 
getMessage(); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: está muito vago. Não temos bola de cristal

Comment: Só com este trecho não é possível saber o problema. Poste o código todo (a parte relevante).

Comment: Quando vc acessa o arquivo php direto acontecesse a mesma coisa? você chama ele no endereço `file:///c:\amp\htdocs\arquivo.php`?

Answer (score 3):

Use sempre `<?php` no começo de um código **PHP** e finalize com `?>`.

Por exemplo, no código que você postou acima a função que é chamada `getMessage()` não está entre tags PHP. Você tem que sempre verificar. Evite usar somente `<?` para iniciar o código PHP. Alguns apaches não estão configurados para usar `short_tags`.

Além do mais, verifique também a extensão do arquivo, se está realmente `.php` . Último ponto a verificar é se o apache que você está executando é um apache ou é o `IIS` (windows). Tente sempre usar apaches como Xampp, Wamp, Vertrigo, etc.

Comment: php short tag não tem relação com o webserver.. mas de qualquer forma, a observação sobre getMessage fora das tags está correta.

Comment: [Por que omitir a tag de fechamento do PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61305/91)