# O que ocasiona o erro de JSON inválido?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json, jquery-datatables

Eu já fiz o que foi dito neste  post: [json_encode - JSON inválido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36835/json-encode-json-inv%C3%A1lido) e ainda não foi resolvido, por isso estou perguntando.

Estou usando o jquery datatables server side. Fiz a ativação server side com o repositório padrão, na tabela datatables_demo no mesmo banco e tudo funcionou. Agora eu só mudei a tabela e gera aquele erro:

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

segui as instruções, debuggei no console do chrome, mas não tem preview disponível. Porque tá acontecendo o erro de JSON Inváldio??? Como eu posso verificar para corrigir o erro?

GENTE ME AJUDA!!!

O QUE EU PRECISO FAZER PARA VOCÊS ME AJUDAREM???

Aqui a resposta do servidor
[image: print]

Meu código da página com a tabela **html**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php",

        "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]]
    } );
} );

</script>
```

E o **server_processing.php**:

```
<?php
$table = 'tbl_medic';
$primaryKey = 'id_Medic';

$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'nome', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'cidade',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'cep',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'crm',     'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'email', 'dt' => 4 ),
    array( 'db' => 'pastaDocumentos',     'dt' => 5 )
);

$sql_details = array(
    'user' => '***', //Usuário do banco de dados
    'pass' => '***', //Senha do banco de dados
    'db'   => '***', //Banco de dados
    'host' => 'localhost'
);

require_once( 'ssp.class.php' );
echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

Comment: Qual o `JSON` que está sendo retornado?

Comment: Pode ser muita coisa. Melhor [edit] a pergunta e colocar a parte relevante do código.

Comment: Então não tem JSON retornando, nada @MarcelodeAndrade

Comment: @bfavaretto, vou editar e mais a tarde eu te chamo, se possível eu peço sua ajuda

Comment: Na pergunta você comentou que está usando o `datatbles`. Por gentileza disponibilize o código que está tentando executar e a estrutura da tabela.   Cada item do `json` deve corresponder a uma coluna da tabela. Por isso da importância da estrutura.

Comment: Editei a pergunta @MarcelodeAndrade

Comment: Editei a pergunta @bfavaretto

Comment: Editei a pergunta @DjalmaManfrin

Comment: Experimentou colocar no php isto `<?php header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');` ?

Comment: Sim, já tentei. Conforme indicado num outro POST aqui mesmo @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Qual postagem John?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36835/json-encode-json-inv%C3%A1lido @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Tem certeza que não tem nenhum espaço antes do `<?php`?

Comment: Sim, certeza absoluta

Comment: Eu fiz um debugg pelo próprio datatable : debug.datatables.net/ujutog @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Mas o problema é no momento do request, por isto creio que o problema seja em outra coisa.

Comment: Deu pra entender minha dúvida? O que eu achei estranho é que em um mesmo banco de dados, duas tabelas diferentes, quando eu coloco a padrão(datatables_demo), funciona normal, e quando eu mudo a tabela(para tbl_medic), id e campos dá esse maldito erro @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Entender eu entendi sim John, a questão é que pode ser qualquer problema, provavelmente você desligou os erros do PHP e não esta conseguindo retornar nada detalhado (ps: recomendo erros ligado em ambiente de desenvolvimento e erros desligados em produção).

Comment: @JohnDoe500 comente o código: `echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns ));` e coloque um `dd();` para vermos o retorno do método. Deve ficar assim: `dd(SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns ));`. Acrescente o resultado na pergunta para analisarmos.